How to calculate business days between date durations in Kusto
I'm trying to calculate the number of business days between dates, and I'm stuck. Here's what I currently have, but I get an error

toscalar operator: Failed to resolve table or scalar expression named "TimeStamp"

for the MyTable table which has a column TimeStamp.
kql:
let CalculateBusinessDays = (startDate: datetime, endDate: datetime) {
    range day from 0 to datetime_diff('day', endDate, startDate) step 1
    | extend currentDate = startDate + day * 1d
    | where dayofweek(currentDate) between (1d .. 5d)
    | summarize BusinessDays = count()
    | project BusinessDays
};
MyTable
| extend businessDays = toscalar(CalculateBusinessDays(now(), TimeStamp))


You can achieve your requirement using the below code.
let MyTable = datatable(TimeStamp: datetime)
[
    datetime(2024-11-11),
    datetime(2024-10-15),
    datetime(2024-12-01)
];

let a= MyTable
| extend day_diff = range(0, datetime_diff('day', TimeStamp, now()), 1)  
| mv-expand day_diff to typeof(int)  
| extend curr_date = now() + day_diff * 1d  
| where dayofweek(curr_date) between (1d .. 5d)  
| summarize BusinessDays = count() by TimeStamp;

MyTable
| join kind=leftouter a on $left.TimeStamp == $right.TimeStamp
| extend BusinessDays = iif(isnull(BusinessDays),0,BusinessDays)
| project TimeStamp,BusinessDays;

Here, it calculates the business days count and left joins the original table with generated table. After the join, the days which are older than the current date will come as null. In the above, it will set it to 0, which means the count of business days from current date to that past date is 0.
Result:


welcome to the community :)
You have asked a really interesting question, as Rakesh's answer this is possible using mv-expand but to do it with a function we hit the limitations of what we can easily do with scalars and tabular data.
I did spend a day thinking about your question and how I'd answer it, and this is my attempt.  However I am pretty confident there is a more performant and elegant method which is unfortunately beyond me at the moment.
let CalculateBusinessDays = (startDate:datetime, endDate:datetime) {
  let CheckBusinessDay = (day:datetime) { iif(dayofweek(day) between (1d .. 5d), true, false) }; //Easily change the working week if needed
  let DaySeries0 = iif(CheckBusinessDay(startDate), range(startDate, endDate, 7d), dynamic(null)); //Create a range from date in 7 day increments...
  let DaySeries1 = iif(CheckBusinessDay(startDate + 1d), range(startDate + 1d, endDate, 7d), dynamic(null)); //..calculate for each possible day of the week...
  let DaySeries2 = iif(CheckBusinessDay(startDate + 2d), range(startDate + 2d, endDate, 7d), dynamic(null)); //..but only generate an array if it's a workday.
  let DaySeries3 = iif(CheckBusinessDay(startDate + 3d), range(startDate + 3d, endDate, 7d), dynamic(null));
  let DaySeries4 = iif(CheckBusinessDay(startDate + 4d), range(startDate + 4d, endDate, 7d), dynamic(null));
  let DaySeries5 = iif(CheckBusinessDay(startDate + 5d), range(startDate + 5d, endDate, 7d), dynamic(null));
  let DaySeries6 = iif(CheckBusinessDay(startDate + 6d), range(startDate + 6d, endDate, 7d), dynamic(null));
  array_length(array_concat(DaySeries0, DaySeries1, DaySeries2, DaySeries3, DaySeries4, DaySeries5, DaySeries6)) //Count all the work days and return the value
};
let MyTable = datatable (Message:string, TimeStamp:datetime) [
'Message1', datetime(2024-09-01),
'Message2', datetime(2024-10-01),
'Message3', datetime(2024-10-23)
];
MyTable
| extend BusinessDays = CalculateBusinessDays(TimeStamp, floor(now(), 1d))




Message
TimeStamp
BusinessDays




Message1
2024-09-01 00:00:00.0000
43


Message2
2024-10-01 00:00:00.0000
22


Message3
2024-10-23 00:00:00.0000
6



